# #sonos unable to play live radio having streaming url m3u8 extension

Tags: sonos

I have implemented same thing refered to doc
http://musicpartners.sonos.com/node/83
for live radio streaming. the streaming url is like http://example.com/abc.m3u8
but this live stream is unable to play by sonos player. please suggest or ask me for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's difficult to answer your question with so little information, but you shouldn't return the streaming URL with getMetadata as it seems you are doing. You should return the URL as a result of getMediaURI requests.

Comment: Can you please attach some logs of the calls Sonos is making to your server, and how you are responding? In particular, as @per_sm said, what are you returning from getMetadata?